# What is an incremental checkpoint (in the context of indirect checkpoints)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, recovery, checkpoint

I was using extended events to trace checkpoint activity of a database with indirect checkpoints enabled. The event stream looks like this:

[image]

And the details of the selected event are:

[image]

The description of the selected event is:

> Chose to enqueue an incremental checkpoint as we are near our recovery
>   target

It was determined using the following query:

```
SELECT name, description FROM sys.dm_xe_objects WHERE name LIKE '%checkpoint%' ORDER BY name
```

I'm trying to better understand how indirect checkpoints work under the covers. **What is an incremental checkpoint?** What IO patterns will it cause? How does it relate to a "normal" checkpoint?

I have studied the [docs about checkpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189573.aspx) but I could not find any information about this.

Comment: This will help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40964/8783

Comment: @Kin thanks. I found that answer to be helpful but it does not reference the term "incremental". I'd like to understand what exactly an incremental checkpoint does.

Comment: I dont think that it is documented in BOL (atleast I could not find), but other people might help you.